# Converting image to byte array?

Tags: image-processing, arrays

What is the need/purpose of converting an image to a byte array?

Why do we need to do this?

Comment: That depends on what you want to accomplish, doesn't it ?

Comment: Your question is too vague. There are plenty of different resons in different situations. You should specify in what situation you are needing this, or you will just get a lot of guesses about what you are doing, and a lot of answers for other slightly related questions that people think that you are really wanting to ask about (like for example *how* to convert an image to a byte array).

Comment: Seems like a homework question. If it is, tag it. At the moment this isn't even relevant to C#. I removed C# from your post. If it actually is a c# specific question, please update your post with something that actually has to do with C#.

Comment: Last time I checked, a image was byte array in the first place. Terrible question.

Comment: This could do with being deleted.

Answer (score 5):

What's the purpose of converting an Image to a byte array?

- Saving an image to disk
- Serializing the image to send to a web service
- Saving the image to a database
- Serializing the image for processing

...are just a few that I can think of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 4):

I think the most common use would be saving an image in a database (`BINARY(MAX)` data type).

Answer (score 2):

Most common is to persist the image in the database as a blob (binary large object) but it could also be used in web services where you could take in a byte array as a method argument and then convert that to an image for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

the only time i've ever needed to do this was to compare two images pixel-by-pixel to see if they were identical (as part of an automated test suite). converting to bytes and pinning the memory allowed me to use an unsafe block in C# to do a direct pointer-based comparison, which was orders of magnitude faster than GetPixel.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I wrote a code to get hash from image, here is how:

```
    private ImageConverter c = new ImageConverter();
    private byte[] getBitmapHash(Bitmap hc) {
        return md5.ComputeHash(c.ConvertTo(hc, typeof(byte[])) as byte[]);
    }
```

Here is this in [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983508/verify-image-sequence). **Serializing** image or adding it to database in **raw byte format** (without mime type) is not something that seems to be sensible, but you can do that. **Image processing** and **cryptography** are most likely of places where this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

To further generalize what Brad said: Serialization and (probably) a basis for object comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Also is helpful if you have a image in memory and want to send it to someone via a protocol (HTTP for example).  A perfect example would be the method "AddBytesForUpload" in the Chilkat HTTPRequest clas [http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/vbnetHttpRequestRef.html].

Why would you ever need to do this you may ask... Well lets assume we have a directory of images we want to auto upload to imageshack, but do some mods before hand like put our domain name at the bottom right.  With this, u load the image in memory, do the mods with it that u need, then simply attach that stream to the HTTPRequest object.  Without the array u would need to then same to a file before uploading, which in turn will create either a new file u then need to delete after, or over write the original, which is not always ideal.

Answer (score -1):

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image image)
{
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 image.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
 return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what i'm asking... i'm asking, why we have to do this conversion?

Answer (score -2):

If it is a image file use File.ReadAllBytes().

Comment: Did you read the "question"?